# LWC -ightning/uiObjectInfoAPI - getting INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS error for custom object

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to get metadata info for a custom object using lightning/uiObjectInfoAPI’

here is what I am doing:

```
wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: BATCH_OBJECT })
    getBatchObjectInfo({data,error})
    {
        console.log('getbatchobjectinfo');
        if(data){
            console.log('the data :'+JSON.stringify(data.fields));
            this.name = data.fields[BATCH_OBJECT_NAME.fieldApiName].label;
        }
        else if(error){
            console.log('the error :'+JSON.stringify(error));
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> {"ok":false,"status":403,"statusText":"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS","body":[{"errorCode":"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS","message":"You
>   don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or
>   to request access."}]}

I checked the system admistrator profile in my scratch org:
there is access to "Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions"

Any reason why is happenning?

I am able to get back all the information related to the object in case of standard object like Account.

Comment: what is the object with variable named BATCH_OBJECT?

Comment: it is a custom object : Batch_Log__c, I had to remove the name space in js file as it was complaining about it. I have this is js file : import BATCH_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Batch_Log__c';

Comment: Check your Profile access to the Batch_Log__c object ? Looks like your profile does not have read access to the Batch_Log__c object

Comment: sharing acces on Batch_Log__c is : Public Read/Write, i am system administrator for my scratch org, I have read and edit access to all the fields in the object. Also, i have Read Create Edit Delete View All  Modify All 
for this Custom Object Permissions. I feel the error is regarding some permission with metadata access. Also, system admin profile has this access too : Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions Checked

Comment: Is it failing for any custom object as well ?

Comment: see here now we have a separate section who has access to metadata, it is no longer automatically available.  https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_custom_metadata_access.htm

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_custom_metadata_require_cruc.htm

Comment: Mohith, just tried for another custom object, same error. Avijit, my issue is regarding accessing metadata of a object not custom metadata type. - thanks !

Comment: Are you on spring 20 org ? That sounds like a bug then from Salesforce

Comment: I created a new LWC and just had this functionality and it is working there. If I add this in my main LWC, it works for standard objects, but gives error for custom object.- thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this issue @Padma. I am getting similar error when calling the LWC from an Aura component and it works fine for the Standard object not for custom object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if there is a reference field in your call that is locked from access that you cannot see due to permissions/sharing? It would appear that this would also throw out an error as you may not have access to the object on the other end of that relationship field so the error is being thrown as it would attempt to pull the Id and Name from reference fields used in the layout.

Answer (score -1):

Can you create the new VSCode project again or delete org folder in .sfdx folder under the project and again authorize dev hub and create scratch org

Comment: I will try doing this, but my code is already in git etc. this functionality is working with a seperate LWC, but in main LWC works for standard objects not custom objects-thanks!

Comment: @Padma: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?